# Flutter - Display selected icon from a list

Tags: flutter, dart, icons

I am creating an Event Management app and when the user creates a new event, they select an icon for the event they are creating.  I would like that specific icon to be displayed with the event name on the home screen.  How do I do that?  Here is the code:

ADD NEW EVENT PAGE:

```js
import 'package:evnt_app/pages/choose_icon_page.dart';
import 'package:evnt_app/pages/navigation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import '../data/evnt_data.dart';
import '../models/category_model.dart';

class AddNewEventPage extends StatefulWidget {
  Category categories;
  AddNewEventPage({super.key, required this.categories});

  @override
  State<AddNewEventPage> createState() => _AddNewEventPageState();
}

class _AddNewEventPageState extends State<AddNewEventPage> {
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////      Controller Methods      /////////////////////////////////////////////////

  // Clear Controllers
  void clearControllers() {
    eventNameController.clear();
    eventDateController.clear();
    eventTimeController.clear();
    eventLocationController.clear();
  }

  // Support Dialog Box - Text Controller
  final eventNameController = TextEditingController();
  final eventDateController = TextEditingController();
  final eventTimeController = TextEditingController();
  final eventLocationController = TextEditingController();

  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////    "Add" Button Method   /////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  // "Add New Event" Save Button Method
  void saveNewEvent() {
    Provider.of<EvntData>(context, listen: false).addEvent(
      eventNameController.text,
      eventDateController.text,
      eventTimeController.text,
      eventLocationController.text,
    );

    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => const Navigation(),
      ),
    );
  }

  // // "Add New Event" Cancel Button Method
  // void cancelAddEvent() {
  //   Navigator.of(context).pop();
  //   clearControllers();
  // }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,

      // App Bar
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).push(
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => const Navigation(),
                ),
              );
            },
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.close,
              size: 30,
            )),
        elevation: 0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.red.shade400,
        title: Text(
          'Add Event Details',
          style: GoogleFonts.poppins(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 20.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            // Event Icon
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 25.0, bottom: 25.0),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).push(
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => const ChooseIconPage(),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(60),
                        color: widget.categories.iconColor,
                      ),
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                        child: Image(
                          image: widget.categories.iconImagePath,
                          width: 80.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            // Event Title Header
            Row(
              children: [
                Text(
                  'Event Name',
                  style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                      fontSize: 16,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                      color: Colors.red.shade400),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            // Event Name Text Field
            TextField(
              controller: eventNameController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: "Enter Event Name",
                hintStyle: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                    fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
              ),
              style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                  fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
            ),

            const SizedBox(height: 25.0),

            // Event Date Header
            Text(
              'Date',
              style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                  fontSize: 16,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                  color: Colors.red.shade400),
            ),
            // Event Date
            TextField(
              controller: eventDateController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: "Enter Date",
                hintStyle: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                    fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
              ),
              style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                  fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
            ),

            const SizedBox(height: 25.0),

            // Event Time Header
            Text(
              'Time',
              style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                  fontSize: 16,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                  color: Colors.red.shade400),
            ),
            // Event Time
            TextField(
              controller: eventTimeController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: "Enter Time",
                hintStyle: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                    fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
              ),
              style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                  fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
            ),

            const SizedBox(height: 25.0),

            // Event Location Header
            Text(
              'Location',
              style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                  fontSize: 16,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                  color: Colors.red.shade400),
            ),
            // Event Location
            TextField(
              controller: eventLocationController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: "Enter Location",
                hintStyle: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                    fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
              ),
              style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                  fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
            ),

            const SizedBox(height: 50.0),

            // Add Event Button
            Column(
              children: [
                Center(
                  child: Container(
                    width: 150,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
                        color: Colors.red.shade400),
                    child: MaterialButton(
                      shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                          Radius.circular(50.0),
                        ),
                      ),
                      minWidth: 150.0,
                      height: 50.0,
                      onPressed: saveNewEvent,
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            'Add',
                            style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                fontSize: 18,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                color: Colors.white),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 25.0),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

CHOOSE ICON PAGE:

```js
import 'package:evnt_app/pages/add_new_event_page.dart';
import 'package:evnt_app/pages/navigation.dart';
import 'package:evnt_app/tiles/category_tile.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import '../data/evnt_data.dart';
import '../models/category_model.dart';

class ChooseIconPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ChooseIconPage({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  State<ChooseIconPage> createState() => _ChooseIconPageState();
}

class _ChooseIconPageState extends State<ChooseIconPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<EvntData>(
      builder: (context, value, child) => Scaffold(
        // AppBar
        appBar: AppBar(
          leading: IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).push(
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => const Navigation(),
                  ),
                );
              },
              icon: const Icon(
                Icons.close,
                size: 30,
              )),
          elevation: 0,
          backgroundColor: Colors.red.shade400,
          title: Text(
            'Choose Icon',
            style:
                GoogleFonts.poppins(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            // CHOOSE AN ICON GRID VIEW
            Container(
              child: Expanded(
                child: GridView.builder(
                  gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                      crossAxisCount: 4),
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  itemCount: value.categories.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    Category individualCategory = value.categories[index];
                    return CategoryTile(
                      categories: individualCategory,
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).push(
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => AddNewEventPage(
                              categories: individualCategory,
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

HOME PAGE:

```js
import 'package:evnt_app/models/upcoming_event_model.dart';
import 'package:evnt_app/pages/individual_past_event_page.dart';
import 'package:evnt_app/pages/individual_upcoming_event_page.dart';
import 'package:evnt_app/tiles/past_event_tile.dart';
import 'package:evnt_app/tiles/upcoming_event_tile.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import '../data/evnt_data.dart';
import '../models/past_event_model.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Curved Main Tile
    return Consumer<EvntData>(
      builder: (context, value, child) => Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade300,
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 100),
              height: 612,
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(50.0),
                  topRight: Radius.circular(50.0),
                ),
              ),
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    //////////////////////////////// PAST EVENTS SECTION ////////////////////////////////
                    Row(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        // Header
                        Text(
                          'Past Events',
                          style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                              fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),

                    // Past Events Icons List
                    Container(
                      height: 175,
                      child: Expanded(
                        child: ListView.builder(
                          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                          itemCount: value.pastEvents.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            PastEvent individualPastEvent =
                                value.pastEvents[index];
                            return Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
                              child: PastEventTile(
                                pastEvents: individualPastEvent,
                                onTap: () {
                                  Navigator.of(context).push(
                                    MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (context) =>
                                          IndividualPastEventPage(
                                        pastEvents: individualPastEvent,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  );
                                },
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),

                    //////////////////////////////// UPCOMING EVENTS SECTION ////////////////////////////////
                    Column(
                      children: [
                        // Header
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                              child: Text(
                                'Upcoming Events',
                                style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                    fontSize: 20,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    color: Colors.red.shade400),
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                        // Upcoming Events Icons List
                        Container(
                          height: 325,
                          child: Expanded(
                            child: ListView.builder(
                              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                              itemCount: value.upcomingEvents.length,
                              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                UpcomingEvent individualUpcomingEvent =
                                    value.upcomingEvents[index];
                                return Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
                                  child: UpcomingEventTile(
                                    upcomingEvents: individualUpcomingEvent,
                                    onTap: () {
                                      Navigator.of(context).push(
                                        MaterialPageRoute(
                                          builder: (context) =>
                                              IndividualUpcomingEventPage(
                                            upcomingEvents:
                                                individualUpcomingEvent,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      );
                                    },
                                  ),
                                );
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

UPCOMING EVENT TILE:

```js
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import '../models/upcoming_event_model.dart';

class UpcomingEventTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final UpcomingEvent upcomingEvents;
  void Function()? onTap;

  UpcomingEventTile(
      {super.key, required this.upcomingEvents, required this.onTap});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        GestureDetector(
          onTap: onTap,
          child: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0, bottom: 20.0),
            width: 400,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.grey.shade100,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
            ),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                // Icon & Description Column
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      // Icon
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          // Container(
                          //   decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          //       borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                          //       color: upcomingEvents
                          //           .iconColor),
                          //   child: Padding(
                          //     padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                          //     child: Image(
                          //       image: upcomingEvents.iconImagePath,
                          //       width: 50,
                          //     ),
                          //   ),
                          // ),
                          const SizedBox(width: 20),
                          // Event Description
                          Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                upcomingEvents.upcomingEventName,
                                style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                    fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                              ),
                              const SizedBox(
                                height: 5.0,
                              ),
                              Text(
                                upcomingEvents.upcomingEventDate,
                                style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                    fontSize: 13,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                    color: Colors.red.shade400),
                              ),
                              Text(
                                upcomingEvents.upcomingEventLocation,
                                style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                    fontSize: 13,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                    color: Colors.grey.shade600),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                // Arrow Icon
                Column(
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0),
                      child: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right_rounded,
                          size: 35, color: Colors.red.shade400),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

SCREENSHOTS:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I can see in the code, in the Add New Event file
You may not send the widget.categories.iconImagePath in the saveNewEvent() method or you may not want to send it with the provider, but the path of this icon does not go to the Upcoming Events page from the Add New Event file in any way. In the ListTile it doesn't go, it comes up empty on the left. As a result, this path does not go to the Add New Event from Coming Events file. Also, I recommend using this instead of the Image widget:

```
      SizedBox(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.2,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.1,
        child: ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: ProjectBorderRadiusUtility().buttonBorderRadius,
          child: FadeInImage.memoryNetwork(
            placeholder: kTransparentImage,
            image: pathOfAdvertImage,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
      )
```

UPDATE:

1.

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class ImageProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  String _imagePath;

  String get imagePath => _imagePath;

  void setImagePath(String path) {
    _imagePath = path;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

2. 

```
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (_) => ImageProvider(),
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}
```

3. 

```
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class ImagePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final imageProvider = Provider.of<ImageProvider>(context, listen: false);

    // Set the image path to here
    imageProvider.setImagePath('path/to/your/image.jpg');

    // page codes
    
  }
}
```

4. 

```
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class AnotherPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final imageProvider = Provider.of<ImageProvider>(context);

   
    final imagePath = imageProvider.imagePath;

    final imageWidget = Image.network(imagePath);

    // page codes
   
  }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the help. I am new to Flutter…only 2 months in. Clean code will come.

Comment: No problem, I hope my answer will help to you. If the answer helped, please mark as answer. Otherwise return to here

Comment: Can I add a controller to an image so that whatever Icon is selected on the "Add New Event" page, the icon is saved along with the text when the "Add" button is selected?  I added a controller for the text field already

Comment: The answer was updated by me.